# Can I define a function that takes a variable parameters based on which selector is active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters, jquery-selectors

I have multiple elements that I want to define a function for (switch-case style)...something like this:

```
$("#s1, #s2").hover({param: *specific selector name*}, switchFunc);

function switchFunc(event) {
    switch (event) {
        case "#s1": do something;
            break;
        case "#s2": do something else;
            break;
    }
}
```

Can I do this somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to define a separate parameter for this, you can simply use `$(this)` to refer to the element on which the event is being fired, or `this.id` to look at its ID, and make a decision based on that within the handler:

```
$("#s1, #s2").hover(switchFunc);

function switchFunc() {
    switch (this.id) {
        case "s1": // do something
            break;
        case "s2": // do something else
            break;
    }
}
```

If you prefer comparing it to a selector, use `$(this).is(selector)`:

```
function switchFunc() {
    if ($(this).is("#s1")) {
        // do something
    } else if ($(this).is("#s2")) {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that binding to hover will have the event fire twice: once for mouseenter, and once for mouseleave. To have it fire only once, bind to the desired mouse event.